# Issue with building debian package from a gradle build

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, debian

When running a gradlew clean build I should output 2 .deb files one for my main service and one to handle db-migrations. When running the build I get both files but the db-migration .deb file is getting an error when another part of the project is trying to run it because it is not a Debian format archive. This is happening after updating the project to java 11 and gradle to 6.5 from java 8 and gradle 4.6. Given the jump many other packages also needed to be updated as well. Given the size of the project I can't give a reproducible example but I am hoping that someone will be able to find some issues with my gradle files.
Here is the main service build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            if (System.env.S3_REPO_URL != null) {
                url System.env.S3_REPO_URL
                authentication {
                    awsIm(AwsImAuthentication)
                }
            } else {
                url repositoryUrl + "/repository/maven/"
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

// binary plugins
plugins {
    id "com.github.node-gradle.node" version "2.2.0"
    id 'java'
    id 'checkstyle'
    id 'com.github.spotbugs' version '4.2.1'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'nebula.ospackage' version '8.5.6'
    id 'org.owasp.dependencycheck' version "8.2.1"
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'eclipse'
}

/*
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.failOnVersionConflict()
}
*/

eclipse {
    classpath {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

// --------------- extra project properties
ext {
    asRelease = '1'
    buildNumber = System.getenv().BUILD_NUMBER ?: UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll('-', '')
    classesOutputDir = System.getProperty('classes.output.dir') ?: sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.asPath
    branchName = System.getenv().BRANCH_NAME ?: System.getenv().USER
    majorminorversion = '3.5'
    artifactVersion = String.format('%s.%s', majorminorversion, buildNumber)
    buildArtifactVersion = String.format('%s.%s', branchName, buildNumber)
    dockerBuildDir = "build/distributions/docker"
}

// --------------- default project properties
// the 'group' and 'version' are used in the build pipeline, any changes will require changes elsewhere
group = 'com.project.platform'
version = artifactVersion

configurations {
    bootstrapRuntime {
        description = 'Bootstrap classpath'
    }
    serviceRuntime {
        description = 'Service classpath'
    }
    jasperreports {
        description = 'Jasper reports classpath'
    }
}
// --------------- project properties added by the java plugin
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
sourceSets {
    version = majorminorversion
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.bootstrapRuntime + configurations.serviceRuntime
        runtimeClasspath += configurations.bootstrapRuntime + configurations.serviceRuntime
    }
    generated {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
        java {
            srcDirs = ['generated']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/dist/resources']
        }
    }
    test {
        compileClasspath += configurations.testCompile
        runtimeClasspath += configurations.testRuntime + project.files(sourceSets.generated.output.classesDirs)
    }
}

configurations.archives.artifacts.removeAll { it.type == 'jar' }

repositories {
    maven {
        if (System.env.S3_REPO_URL != null) {
            url System.env.S3_REPO_URL
            authentication {
                awsIm(AwsImAuthentication)
            }
        } else {
            url repositoryUrl + "/repository/maven/"
        }
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   // removed to meet space requirements for github
}

[configurations.runtime, configurations.default, configurations.bootstrapRuntime, configurations.serviceRuntime]*.exclude(module: 'commons-logging')

[configurations.testCompile, configurations.testRuntime]*.exclude(group: 'org.mortbay.jetty', module: 'servlet-api-2.5')

def pseudoBundleFile = file("${buildDir}/i18nBundles/pse_udo.json")
tasks.register('buildPseudoBundle', JavaExec) {
    dependsOn compileTestJava
    main = 'com.i18n.PseudoLocGenerator'
    args pseudoBundleFile
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
}

// Add the debian and rpm files to the archives configuration. The uploadArchives task depends on the
// archives configuration to determine what artifacts need to be uploaded.
artifacts {
    archives file: file("build/distributions/${name}_${artifactVersion}-${asRelease}_all.deb"),
            name: project.name
    archives file: file("build/distributions/${name}-${artifactVersion}-${asRelease}.noarch.rpm"),
            name: project.name,
            extension: 'rpm',
            classifier: null
    archives file: file("db-migrations/build/distributions/service-migration_${artifactVersion}-${asRelease}_all.deb"),
            name: 'service-migration',
            classifier: 'all'
    archives file: file("db-migrations/build/distributions/service-migration-${artifactVersion}-${asRelease}.noarch.rpm"),
            name: 'service-migration',
            extension: 'rpm',
            classifier: null
    archives file: pseudoBundleFile, builtBy: buildPseudoBundle
}

uploadArchives {
    version = artifactVersion
    repositories {
        ivy {
            if (System.env.S3_ART_URL != null) {
                url System.env.S3_ART_URL
                authentication {
                    awsIm(AwsImAuthentication)
                }
            } else {
                credentials {
                    username ""
                    password ""
                }
                url repositoryUrl + "/repository/maven-hosted/"
            }
            layout 'pattern', {
                artifact '[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier])(.[ext])'
                ivy '[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml'
                m2compatible = true
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.register('copyGitHooks', Copy) {
    from('config/git-hooks')
    into('.git/hooks')
}
compileJava.dependsOn copyGitHooks

jar.enabled = false

processResources.doFirst {
    ant.propertyfile(file: "src/main/resources/version.properties") {
        entry(key: "build.version", value: majorminorversion)
        entry(key: "build.number", value: buildNumber)
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    include 'com/project/**'
    exclude 'com/project/**/*IntegrationTest.class'
    exclude 'com/acceptance/**'

    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
    }
    reports.html.destination = file("${reporting.baseDir}/unitTests")
}

tasks.register('applyFilters', Copy) {
    from('build/webapp') {
        include 'WEB-INF/ftl/admin/index.ftl'
        include 'WEB-INF/ftl/webapp/index.ftl'
        include 'WEB-INF/ftl/account/upgrade.ftl'

        filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [version: majorminorversion])
    }
    into 'build/filtered'
}

ospackage {
    packageName = project.name
    version = artifactVersion
    release = asRelease

    packageDescription = "Project Service"
    os = LINUX
    user = "root"
    permissionGroup = "root"
    url = 'http://www.project.com'
    packageGroup = 'Development'
    packager = 'Project Engineering Team'
    summary = 'Service'
    vendor = 'Project'

    //Debian installation settings
    def installationDir = '/usr/share/' + packageName
    def configDir = '/etc/' + packageName

    into installationDir

    from(configurations.bootstrapRuntime) {
        fileMode = 0644
        into 'lib'
    }
    from(sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs) {
        fileMode = 0644
        include '*.class'
        include 'com/project/web/metrics/Metrics.class'
        include 'com/project/migration/check/**/*.class'
        include 'com/project/security/sessionmanagement/*.class'
        include 'com/project/util/ApplicationContextProvider.class'
        include 'logback.xml'
        include 'databaseMigrationCheckContext.xml'
        include 'database/migration/**'
        into 'classes'
    }
    from('src/main/resources') {
        fileMode = 0644
        include 'database/**'
        include 'logback.xml'
        include 'databaseMigrationCheckContext.xml'
        into 'classes'
    }
    from('src/main/webapp') {
        fileMode = 0644
        include 'WEB-INF/**'
        include 'web/**'
        exclude 'WEB-INF/ftl/webapp/index.ftl'
        exclude 'WEB-INF/ftl/admin/index.ftl'
        exclude 'WEB-INF/ftl/account/upgrade.ftl'        
        into 'webapp'
    }
    from('build/webapp') {
        fileMode = 0644
        include 'WEB-INF/**'
        include 'web/**'
        exclude 'WEB-INF/ftl/webapp/index.ftl'
        exclude 'WEB-INF/ftl/admin/index.ftl'
        exclude 'WEB-INF/ftl/account/upgrade.ftl'
        into 'webapp'
    }
    from('build/filtered') {
        fileMode = 0644
        into 'webapp'
    }
    def bundledLibraries = configurations.serviceRuntime
    bundledLibraries -= configurations.bootstrapRuntime
    from(bundledLibraries) {
        fileMode = 0644
        into 'webapp/WEB-INF/lib'
    }
    from(sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs) {
        fileMode = 0644
        exclude '*.class'
        exclude 'com/project/web/metrics/Metrics.class'
        exclude 'com/project/migration/check/**/*.class'
        exclude 'com/project/security/sessionmanagement/*.class'
        exclude 'com/project/util/ApplicationContextProvider.class'
        exclude 'logback.xml'
        exclude 'databaseMigrationCheckContext.xml'
        exclude 'database/migration/**'        
        into 'webapp/WEB-INF/classes'
    }
    from('src/main/resources') {
        fileMode = 0644
        include 'version.properties'
        include 'ValidationMessages.properties'
        include 'report/images/**'
        include 'office-templates/**'
        into 'webapp/WEB-INF/classes'
    }
    from('src/main/dist') {
        fileMode = 0644
        exclude 'resources'
        exclude 'wrapper'
        exclude 'bin'
        into ''
    }
    from('installation/config') {
        fileMode = 0644
        into configDir
    }
    from('src/main/dist/resources/config') {
        fileMode = 0640
        exclude 'overrides/**'
        exclude 'loggerConfig.xml'
        configurationFile 'rateLimiter.yml'
        rename('config.properties', 'default.config.properties')
        into configDir
    }
    from('src/main/dist/resources/config/overrides') {
        fileMode = 0640
        include 'postgres.config.properties'
        include 'oracle.config.properties'
        into configDir + '/config-examples'
        rename { String fileName ->
            fileName.replace('properties', 'example')
        }
    }
    from('src/main/dist/resources/config/overrides') {
        fileMode = 0640
        fileType CONFIG | NOREPLACE
        include 'local.config.properties'
        into configDir
        rename { String fileName ->
            'config.properties'
        }
    }
    from('docs/licenses') {
        include 'licenses.html'
        include 'licenses.md'
        into 'licenses'
    }
}

buildDeb { // deb 11 bullseye

    configurationFile('/etc/service/rateLimiter.yml')
    preInstall file('installation/scripts/deb/preInstall.sh')
    postInstall file('installation/scripts/deb/postInstall.sh')
    preUninstall file('installation/scripts/deb/preUninstall.sh')

    requires('adduser')
    //Commenting out the below line as docker build fails when openjdk:8-jre is used
    //requires('java7-runtime-headless')
    requires('service-wrapper')

    def jswConfigDir = 'installation/jsw/deb'

    from(jswConfigDir) {
        fileMode = 0755
        exclude 'wrapper.conf'
        into '/usr/share/service/bin'
    }
    from(jswConfigDir) {
        fileMode = 0644
        include 'wrapper.conf'
        into '/etc/service'
    }

}

tasks.register('buildDockerDeb', Copy) {
    from buildDeb
    from 'Dockerfile'
    from 'installation/scripts/docker/run-in-docker'
    into dockerBuildDir
    rename '(.+)\\.deb', project.name + '.deb'
}

buildRpm {
    arch = NOARCH

    configurationFile('/etc/service/rateLimiter.yml')
    preInstall file('installation/scripts/rpm/preInstall.sh')
    postInstall file('installation/scripts/rpm/postInstall.sh')
    preUninstall file('installation/scripts/rpm/preUninstall.sh')

    requires('java-service-wrapper')
    requires('chkconfig')

    def jswConfigDir = 'installation/jsw/rpm'

    link('/etc/init.d/service', '/usr/share/service/bin/service.sh')

    from(jswConfigDir) {
        fileMode = 0755
        exclude 'wrapper.conf'
        into '/usr/share/service/bin'
    }
    from(jswConfigDir) {
        fileMode = 0644
        fileType CONFIG | NOREPLACE
        include 'wrapper.conf'
        into '/etc/service'
    }
}

buildDeb.dependsOn applyFilters
buildRpm.dependsOn applyFilters

tasks.withType(Test).configureEach {
    systemProperty 'server.connect.url', 'http://localhost:8080'
    systemProperty 'secure.objects.config.path', './src/main/dist/resources/config'
    systemProperty 'secure.objects.config.overrides', './src/main/dist/resources/config/overrides/local.config.properties'
    systemProperty 'secure.objects.web.freemarker', './src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ftl'
    systemProperty 'secure.objects.home', '.'
    systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'staticServe,rngServer'
    systemProperty 'secure.objects.test.config.path', './src/test/resources'

    environment 'SO_MASTER_KEY', 'password'
}

tasks.register('acceptanceTest', Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    dependsOn testClasses
    systemProperties = System.properties
    systemProperty 'service.jwt.key', ''
    include 'com/acceptance/api/**'
    include 'com/acceptance/websocket/**'
    if (project.hasProperty('excludeTests')) {
        exclude project.property('excludeTests')
    }
    testLogging {
        events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut"
    }
    reports.html.destination = file("${reporting.baseDir}/acceptanceTests")
}

tasks.register('browserTestClient', Test) {
    dependsOn testClasses
    systemProperties = System.properties
    include 'com/acceptance/browser/webclient/**'
    exclude 'com/acceptance/browser/webclient/*CleanupData*'

    testLogging {
        events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut"
    }
}

tasks.register('browserTestCleanup', Test) {
    dependsOn testClasses
    systemProperties = System.properties
    include 'com/acceptance/browser/webclient/*CleanupData*'
}


tasks.register('browserTestConsole', Test) {
    dependsOn testClasses
    systemProperties = System.properties
    include 'com/acceptance/browser/adminconsole/**'

    testLogging {
        events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask { task ->
    if (task == browserTestClient) {
        // clean up user data
        println "executing $task ..."
        browserTestCleanup.execute()
    }
}

tasks.register('deleteTestUsers', Test) {
    dependsOn testClasses
    include 'com/acceptance/cleanup/testdata/**'
    systemProperties = System.properties

    testLogging {
        events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}

tasks.withType(Exec).configureEach {
    environment PATH: '/usr/local/bin:' + getEnvironment().get('PATH')
}

node {
    version = '8.10.0'
    npmVersion = '5.6.0'
    download = true
    nodeModulesDir = file('frontend/')
    distBaseUrl = 'http://nodejs.org/dist'
    npmWorkDir = file('frontend/')
    workDir = file('frontend/')
}

checkstyle {
    configProperties = [basedir: projectDir]
    sourceSets = [sourceSets.main, sourceSets.test]
}

 spotbugs {
    toolVersion = '4.2.1'
     ignoreFailures = false
     excludeFilter = file("$projectDir/config/findbugs/excludeFilter.xml")
}

jacocoTestReport {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
    getAdditionalSourceDirs().setFrom(files(sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs))
}

tasks.register('gradleWrapper', Wrapper) {
    description 'Generates the Gradle wrapper files.'
    gradleVersion = '6.5'
}

tasks.register('runService', JavaExec) {
    dependsOn compileJava, compileTestJava
    main = 'ApplicationRunner'
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    jvmArgs '-Dsecure.objects.home=.', '-Dsecure.objects.config.path=./src/main/dist/resources/config',
            '-Dsecure.objects.config.overrides=./src/main/dist/resources/config/overrides/local.config.properties',
            '-Dsecure.objects.web.freemarker=./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ftl', '-DLOG_APPENDER=CONSOLE',
            '-Djava.awt.headless=true', '-Xmx2500m', '-XX:MaxPermSize=1G'
    args 'hsql', 'greenmail', 'dev', '8080', '/'
    environment 'SO_MASTER_KEY', 'password'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        service(MavenPublication) {
            artifact source: buildDeb, extension: 'deb'
            artifact source: buildRpm, extension: 'rpm'
            groupId 'com.project.platform'
            artifactId 'service'
            version buildArtifactVersion
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'NexusBuilds'
            url "${repositoryUrl}/repository/maven-builds/"
            credentials {
                username ""
                password ""
            }
        }
    }
}

task printMajorMinorVersion doLast {
    print majorminorversion
}

jar.dependsOn npm_run_build
buildDeb.dependsOn classes
buildRpm.dependsOn classes
assemble.dependsOn buildDeb, buildRpm, buildDockerDeb, buildPseudoBundle
```

And here is the service-migration build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            if (System.env.S3_REPO_URL != null) {
                url System.env.S3_REPO_URL
                authentication {
                    awsIm(AwsImAuthentication)
                }
            } else {
                url repositoryUrl + "/repository/maven/"
            }
        }
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.13'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'checkstyle'
    id 'nebula.ospackage'
    id 'eclipse'
}

project.version = rootProject.majorminorversion
project.group = 'com.project'

repositories {
    maven {
        if (System.env.S3_REPO_URL != null) {
            url System.env.S3_REPO_URL
            authentication {
                awsIm(AwsImAuthentication)
            }
        } else {
            url repositoryUrl + "/repository/maven/"
        }
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11',
            'commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0',
            'net.jmatrix:eproperties:1.1.5', // todo
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2',
            'com.googlecode.flyway:flyway-core:2.1.1',
            'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3',
            'com.google.guava:guava:30.0-jre',
            'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.3', // todo
            'org.jasypt:jasypt-spring31:1.9.2', // todo
            'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3',
            'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1212',
            'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter',
            'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.29',
            'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:9.0.0.M15'

    runtimeOnly 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:5.2',
            'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3',
            'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1',
            'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.14.1',
            'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.14.1',
            'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2',
    'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2'

}

jar {
    exclude('logback.xml')
}

ospackage {
    packageName = 'service-migration'
    packageDescription = "Project Service Database Migration"
    os = LINUX
    user = "root"
    permissionGroup = "root"
    release = rootProject.asRelease
    version = rootProject.artifactVersion

    url = 'http://www.project.com'
    packageGroup = 'Development'
    packager = 'Project Engineering Team'
    summary = 'Service Database Migration'
    vendor = 'Project'

    //Debian installation settings
    def installationDir = '/usr/share/' + packageName
    def binDir = '/usr/bin'
    def configDir = '/etc/' + packageName

    from('build/libs') {
        fileMode = 0644
        include '*.jar'
        into installationDir
        rename { String fileName ->
            'service-migration.jar'
        }
    }

    from('dist') {
        fileMode = 0644
        exclude 'bin'
        exclude 'config'
        exclude 'i18nBundles/pse_udo.json'
        into installationDir
    }

    from('dist/bin') {
        fileMode = 0755
        into binDir
    }

    from('src/main/resources') {
        fileMode = 0640
        into configDir
        include 'logback.xml'
    }

    from('dist/config/postgres') {
        fileMode = 0640
        into configDir
        rename { String fileName ->
            'config.yml'
        }
    }

    from('dist/config') {
        fileMode = 0640
        into configDir
        rename { String fileName ->
            'config.yml.example'
        }
    }
}

buildDeb {
    postInstall file('installation/deb/postInstall.sh')
}

tasks.register('buildDockerDeb', Copy) {
    from buildDeb
    into rootProject.dockerBuildDir
    rename { filename -> return "service-migration.deb" }
}

buildRpm {
    postInstall file('installation/rpm/postInstall.sh')
}

clean {
    delete "log"
}

tasks.register('runHsqlMigration', JavaExec) {
    dependsOn build
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main 'com.project.migration.Migration'
    systemProperty 'hsql.db.location', '../build/database/so'
    systemProperty 'i18n.bundledir', project.rootDir.absolutePath + '/db-migrations/dist/i18nBundles'
    systemProperty 'LOG_APPENDER', 'CONSOLE'
}

tasks.register('runPostgresMigration', JavaExec) {
    dependsOn build
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main 'com.project.migration.Migration'
    environment 'SO_MASTER_KEY', 'password'
    systemProperty 'spring.config.location', 'dist/config/postgres/application.yml'
    systemProperty 'i18n.bundledir', project.rootDir.absolutePath + '/db-migrations/dist/i18nBundles'
    systemProperty 'LOG_APPENDER', 'CONSOLE'
}

tasks.register('runOracleMigration', JavaExec) {
    dependsOn build
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main 'com.project.migration.Migration'
    environment 'SO_MASTER_KEY', 'password'
    systemProperty 'spring.config.location', 'dist/config/oracle/application.yml'
    systemProperty 'i18n.bundledir', project.rootDir.absolutePath + '/db-migrations/dist/i18nBundles'
    systemProperty 'LOG_APPENDER', 'CONSOLE'
}

checkstyle {
    configProperties = [basedir: rootProject.projectDir]
    configFile rootProject.file('config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml')
}

bootJar {
    mainClass.set('com.project.migration.Migration')
}

publishing {
    publications {
        dbMigration(MavenPublication) {
            artifact source: buildDeb, classifier: 'all', extension: 'deb'
            artifact source: buildRpm, extension: 'rpm'
            groupId 'com.project.platform'
            artifactId 'service-migration'
            version buildArtifactVersion
        }
    }
}

buildDeb.dependsOn bootJar
buildRpm.dependsOn bootJar
assemble.dependsOn buildDeb, buildRpm, buildDockerDeb
```

Please let me know if there is any other information that would be helpful.

Because the .deb file for the main service appears to have been built correctly I tried removing the nebula.ospackage and tried building the .deb directly using the following.

```
tasks.register('createDebPackage', Exec) {
    doFirst {
        def packageName = 'service-migration'
        def version = majorminorversion + '-SNAPSHOT'
        def installationDir = "/usr/share/$packageName"
        def binDir = "/usr/bin"
        def configDir = "/etc/$packageName"
        copy {
            from configurations.runtimeClasspath
            into "$installationDir"
            rename { String fileName ->
                "service-migration.jar"
            }
        }
        copy {
            from "$projectDir/dist"
            exclude 'bin'
            exclude 'config'
            exclude "i18nBundles/pse_udo.json"
            into "$installationDir"
        }
        copy {
            from "$projectDir/dist/bin"
            into "$binDir"
        }
        copy {
            from "$projectDir/src/main/resources"
            include 'logback.xml'
            into "$configDir"
        }
        copy {
            from "$projectDir/dist/config/postgres"
            rename { String fileName ->
                'config.yml'
            }
            into "$configDir"
        }
        copy {
            from "$projectDir/dist/config"
            rename { String fileName ->
                'config.yml.example'
            }
            into "$configDir"
        }
    }
    // Use dpkg-deb to build the package
    commandLine 'dpkg-deb', '--build', "${buildDir}/deb/${packageName}"
    doLast {
        println "Debian package created at ${buildDir}/deb/${packageName}.deb"
    }
}
.....
createDebPackage.dependsOn bootJar
assemble.dependsOn createDebPackage
```

When running this it fails because it is unable to create the directory for the service migration
with the following error

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':db-migrations:createDebPackage'.

> Could not copy file '/home/escott/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.11/68e9a6adf7cf8eb7e9d31bbc554c7c75eeaac568/commons-lang3-3.11.jar' to '/usr/share/service-migration/service-migration.jar'.
> Failed to create directory '/usr/share/service-migration'

I'm not sure if this is related to the issue using the ospackage because the .deb file is created just broken, but I thought it was worth mentioning.